# Complete metrics in locally compact topological groups

Tags: topological-groups

Hello,

I am trying to show that every metrizable locally compact topological group admits a complete metric generating the topology of the group

Comment: Could you please give some background or motivation (why do you want to know? why do you think it's true? for which examples do you know it's true? etc)

Comment: suggestions: Choose one side, say left.  Show that the left uniformity is complete.  Show that a left-invariant metric exists.  Relate these two.

Comment: If you make the completion of the metric space (taking the Cauchy sequences) this is coherent by algebraic group operations


Answer (score 10):

Every second countable, locally compact group admits a metric which is left-invariant, generates the topology, and is proper (i.e. closed balls are compact). See Theorem 4.5 in
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606794

Such a metric is clearly complete.

Comment: However, the solution for the homework-type problem proposed was known long before 2006.

Comment: @Gerald: Indeed, Yves Cornulier just pointed out to me this paper: 

Struble, Raimond A.
Metrics in locally compact groups. Compositio Mathematica, 28 no. 3 (1974), p. 
217-222

http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=CM_1974__28_3_217_0




Comment: A related result from 1951: ["Invariant Metrics in Groups" by V.L. Klee Jr.](https://www.ams.org/proc/1952-003-03/S0002-9939-1952-0047250-4/S0002-9939-1952-0047250-4.pdf), in which it is shown that every Abelian, completely metrizable group admits a complete invariant metric.

Comment: @AlainValette I cannot see the link anymore...to the numdam paper, do you know where it has traveled? Merci en avance :)